# Angular2 + Es6. Render child component

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get a hold of angular2 with ES6, no TypeScript. The problem is that I can't figure out how to render a child component. I have this base-component, which just holds the app. In that component I want to be able to also render, lets say, a header-component and a footer-component. Right now only my base-component gets rendered.

How would I do that?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <application>
        <header></header>
    </application>

    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

app.js

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Header} from './components/app.header';

class Base {
    static get annotations() {
        return [
            new Component({
                selector: "body",
                template: '<application>base</application>'
            }),
        ];
    }

    constructor () {}
}

export {Base};

bootstrap(Base);
```

app.header.js

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

class Header {
    static get annotations() {
        return [
            new Component({
                selector: 'header',
                template: '<h1>header</h1>'
            }),
        ];
    }

    constructor () {}
}

export {Header};
```

Comment: I'm still not getting this right. Anyone having a solution?

Comment: Could you add your code into a github repo or a plunker so we can help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is how you're defining your selectors and templates.

**In index.html**

Change:

```
<body>
    <application>
        <header></header>
    </application>
```

Into:

```
<body>
    <application></application>
```

**In app.js**

```
new Component({
    selector: "application",
    template: '<app-header></app-header>'
}),
```

Then you could change your app.js template to include the footer:

```
new Component({
    selector: "application",
    template: '<app-header></app-header><app-footer></app-footer>'
}),
```

You normally don't want anything between your tags:

```
<application>Nothing goes here</application>
<app-header>Nothing goes here</app-header>
<app-footer>Nothing goes here</app-footer>
```

Unless these are "structural directives" that behave like `*ngIf` or `*ngFor`. Here's the docs:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for the answer, things got a little bit more clear. Now all three elements get rendered (application,header, footer). But header and footer are empty. How can i add some content to them?

Comment: I want to to that from their corresponding files. Like you see above, i want to populate '<header>' from 'app.header.js'.

Comment: That's what should be happening. Just add content to your app.header template. However, you may want to choose different selectors. Maybe `app-header` instead of `header` and `app-footer` instead of `footer`, since `header` and `footer` are legitimate HTML tags. I will change my answer to reflect this.